# Postfix Email Troubleshooting

Tags: linux, postfix, smtp

I'm having some trouble changing the server I use for Postfix emails.

I've installed postfix on the Linux server (CentOS 5) and setup as follows.

I added the settings to the /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
relayhost=imap.googlemail.com

smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

Then I created the /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd file with the contents

```
imap.googlemail.com fake_usernm:fake_passwd
```

Mapped it in with

```
postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

Then everything was working fine but now when I try to change the relayhost to an smtp server mail.example.co.za:26, the email doesn't seem to be sending. I have the checked the maillog which has the following

```
Sep  7 09:30:23 dev postfix/pickup[32641]: E8BF874E3D4: uid=0 from=<root>
Sep  7 09:30:23 dev postfix/cleanup[32691]: E8BF874E3D4: message-id=<20150907073023.E8BF874E3D4@dev.server.com>
Sep  7 09:30:23 dev postfix/qmgr[32642]: E8BF874E3D4: from=<root@dev.server.com>, size=333, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep  7 09:30:26 dev postfix/smtp[32693]: certificate verification failed for mail.example.co.za: num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
Sep  7 09:30:26 dev postfix/smtp[32693]: certificate verification failed for mail.example.co.za: num=27:certificate not trusted
Sep  7 09:30:28 dev postfix/smtp[32693]: E8BF874E3D4: to=<trent@example.co.za>, relay=mail.example.co.za[198.57.162.234]:26, delay=4.4, delays=0.07/0.02/3.8/0.51, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mail.example.co.za[198.57.162.234] said: 550-Verification failed for <root@dev.server.com> 550-The mail server could not deliver mail to root@dev.server.com.  The account or domain may not exist, they may be blacklisted, or missing the proper dns entries. 550 Sender verify failed (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Sep  7 09:30:28 dev postfix/cleanup[32691]: 9D7D374E3D6: message-id=<20150907073028.9D7D374E3D6@dev.server.com>
Sep  7 09:30:28 dev postfix/qmgr[32642]: 9D7D374E3D6: from=<>, size=2642, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep  7 09:30:28 dev postfix/bounce[32695]: E8BF874E3D4: sender non-delivery notification: 9D7D374E3D6
Sep  7 09:30:28 dev postfix/qmgr[32642]: E8BF874E3D4: removed
Sep  7 09:30:28 dev postfix/cleanup[32691]: A72DF74E3D1: message-id=<20150907073028.9D7D374E3D6@dev.server.com>
Sep  7 09:30:28 dev postfix/qmgr[32642]: A72DF74E3D1: from=<>, size=2777, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep  7 09:30:28 dev postfix/local[32696]: 9D7D374E3D6: to=<root@dev.server.com>, relay=local, delay=0.06, delays=0.03/0.01/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (forwarded as A72DF74E3D1)
Sep  7 09:30:28 dev postfix/qmgr[32642]: 9D7D374E3D6: removed
Sep  7 09:30:31 dev postfix/smtp[32693]: certificate verification failed for mail.example.co.za: num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
Sep  7 09:30:31 dev postfix/smtp[32693]: certificate verification failed for mail.example.co.za: num=27:certificate not trusted
```

I don't know what's different and how to go about fixing this

Comment: The certificate sent by `mail.example.co.za` is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The errors I was getting seemed to actually be caused by faults in the servers /etc/hosts file.

I was able to reconfigure the hosts file and test

```
# hostname
```

output was correct with

```
dev.server.com
```

However

```
# hostname -f
```

Would output errors but after reconfiguration it would output

```
dev.server.com
```

Which is correct and fixed the issues I was having with the relay host